# Is there a way to whitelist domains in google chrome for iframes?

Tags: google-chrome, security, iframe

Based on the Chrome settings here - https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug that where basically turned on in Chrome (and pretty much every other major browser) users that work with me can no longer get content iframed from a different domain.

I get the security - not knocking it.   But we are running off of three domains right now and I would like to whitelist - as safe - the other domains so they can play in iframes.   Is there a way to whitelist URLs to deem as safe for samesite cookie orientation?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be that of
[Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing),
defined as:

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served.

As you control the source websites, the web-servers will need to add to their
response the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, as described in the W3C standard
[Access Control for Cross-Site Requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/).

Specifically for Chrome, you may be able as a stop-gap measure to use the following
extensions:

- [Cross Domain - CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cross-domain-cors/mjhpgnbimicffchbodmgfnemoghjakai)
- [Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)

Comment: you are right that it is a CORS issue.   So there isn't a way to define a whitelist natively inside of Chrome or to the registry?    I am wondering of the acceptability of a chrome (any browser) plugin security-wise.    Is there vetting via google or chromium project?   On a side note these plugins seem all over the place with reviews.   I would prefer to script and send out changes via AD profile but I guess I could send down a plugin too.   (if security team oks it)

Comment: Is it possible to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the three domains?